# How to print the response from a post request

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to make a simple search bar for daycares that match the word I input, I'm sending a post request to an api and I get back all the daycares that matched what I typed, here's my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
    <h1 class="mt-3">Busca una guarderia</h1>
    <div class=" mx-1 mb-5">
    <b-form @submit.prevent="buscarGuarderia">    
    <b-form-group id="input-group-1" label-for="input-1">
          <b-form-input
            id="input-1"  
            v-model="cadena"
            required          
          >          
          </b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
    <div class="mt-2">
    </div>
    <b-button block pill type="submit" variant="success">
        Buscar
    </b-button>
    </b-form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  name: "SearchDaycare",
  data() {
    return {
    currentUser: {},
    cadena: ""
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["daycares"]),
  },
  methods: { 
      getDaycare(){
      this.$store.dispatch("getDogDayCares", {
          user: this.currentUser.user
          });
    },
      buscarGuarderia() {      
      this.$store.dispatch("buscarGuarderia", [{
        cadena: this.cadena,
      }, "clients"])
      .then();
    }
  },
    created() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
        try {
            this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        } catch (e) {
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            }
        }
    }

};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
h1 {
  color: #40db9a;
}
.body {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
}
.card {
  color: #063869;
  background-color: #eef6e1;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px 2px rgba(black, 0.6);
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.card:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -2rem;
}
.card:not(:last-child):hover,
.card:not(:last-child):focus-within {
  transform: translateY(-1rem);
  ~ .card {
    transform: translateX(2rem);
  }
}
</style>
```

Here's the buscarGuarderia function which is the one that sends the request to an API

```
buscarGuarderia({ commit }, [credentials, userClass]) {
  return axios.post("/api/" + userClass + "/searchdaycarebyname", credentials).then();
}
```

It works fine, I send the post request and get a response from the API, what I want to do is print the response or responses that I get, I'm having trouble doing this, any help would be appreciated [here's an image of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbt3N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `then` you can fill the sucess response:

```
buscarGuarderia({ commit }, [credentials, userClass]) {
  return axios.post("/api/" + userClass + "/searchdaycarebyname", credentials)
              .then(function(response){
                  console.log(response.data)
               });
}
```

Comment: I phrased myself incorrectly, i don't want to print the response in console , i want to show the response in the component, so when i use the search bar it shows me the data, any chance you could help me with this, i'm new to vue, and implementing this has been really hard, thanks for the first response by the way

Answer (score 0):

You can create one state in vuex to store the response, one mutation to update the state. In the `buscarGuarderia` action, you can call that mutation to update the store state.

Finally, in the vue components that you want to show the response, just load from the store.